# Remove GmsBoundBrokerService from app's process

Tags: android, google-play-services

I constantly see the Service `GmsBoundBrokerService` showing up in running services under my app which is taking whooping ~150 MB of RAM. How to stop the service?

A quick search on SO reveals people complaining about `MeasurementBrokerService` which isn't the case for me. However, I still applied the solution to remove the firebase-analytics completely. So here's what I tried so far which isn't working:

AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />

<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService"
                 tools:replace="android:enabled"
                 android:enabled="false"
                 android:exported="false" />

<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.GmsBoundBrokerService"
                 tools:replace="android:enabled"
                 android:enabled="false"
                 android:exported="false" />
```

build.gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
}
```

If someone has tackled this or have some insights, then please share.

Comment: Hello, facing the same issue. Have you found any hints?

Comment: @ElioKhattar Hi, If I remember correct, then starting the service in separate process helped me with this.

Comment: thanks, yes i confirm the change. Would you mind answering your own questions to help other people here? thank  you.

Comment: @ElioKhattar TBH, I didn't get much time to confirm after I made the service to run in remote process. But since now we are two too notice this difference, I'll definitely post this so it helps others too :)

Answer (score 2):

What finally helped a bit was to run my service in different process.

```
<service
  android:name="com.my.service"
  android:process=":myFancyProcess" />
```